# Scrollbar css mobile or tablet not visible with IOS iphone, ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, scrollbar, overflow

i've spent maybe two days reading forum without a solution to my problem.
I need to display a scrollbar to scroll inside a div a canvas that contains a generated image.

Here is my code :

```js
var c = document.getElementById("graph_statistic");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
```

```css
#first_el::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;  
}
  
#first_el::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

#first_el::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

#first_el::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

#footer{
padding:2em 2em 2em 1em;
font-size:2em;
}
.clr{
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="first_el" style="margin:0 auto 0 auto;float:left;padding:0;overflow:auto;">
 <div id="second_el" style="margin:0px auto;max-height:400px;width:400px;">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
   <canvas width="800" height="800" id="graph_statistic"></canvas>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div id="footer">
A footer
</div>
```

It works great with Android Mobile, but not with Ipad, Iphone...

I've tried so many css code but i failed... ( -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; ) -> no effect

Is possible ?

Comment: Anyone knows the answer ?